# Entity Framework code first - cant add new class

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'm using code first and I set up my enviernment and all was well. Problem is I'm comming back later and needed to add a new class (Foo) e.g.

```
public class NorthwindContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    ...
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; } // added
}

public class Foo // added
{
    public string FooID { get; set; }
    public int Payload { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
...
```

However now whenever I try to update my service reference I get an error. If I take out the

```
public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
```

All is well except there are no Foos in the generated code. What I'm I missing?

Comment: Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few options to resolve the problem. Remove the `IncludeMetadataConvention` included in your context. Then manually delete the database.

```
public class NorthwindContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

or set the initializer in your programs entry point.

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<NorthwindContext>());
```

Final option would be to use [Code First Migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/11/29/code-first-migrations-beta-1-released.aspx) which is still in beta.